# unable to scroll smoothly in eclipse-luna(ubuntu-12.04)

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, eclipse-luna, touchpad

I have eclipse luna in my system.Scrolling function using touchpad is not working smoothly in the editor-view alone(it works properly in other views i.e project explorer,outline etc..).I am using ubuntu-12.04.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related to this bug maybe: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=434898 (vertical scrolling slow and lagging behind scrollwheel)

Comment: The same issue for me in Ubuntu 14.04 with Eclipse Neon. Did you find solution?

Comment: @beemaster check out Sagar Rohankar's answer. it solved it for me on linux mint with eclipse neon. Had horrible slow scrolling and tearing.

Answer (score 3):

Switch Eclipse theme to other than *GTK* (I tried 'Classic' theme on Eclipse Neon and I can observe the smooth scrolling)

Answer (score 1):

I have found temporary solution by forcing Eclipse (4.6) to use GTK2. I've edited file 'eclipse.ini' so the first lines looks like:
`-startup
    plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar
    --launcher.library
    plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.400.v20160518-1444
    --launcher.GTK_version
    2`

Answer (score 1):

You can also try switching to GTK2 `export SWT_GTK3=0; ./eclipse` see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36825434/1641916)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try resetting eclipse? You have to use another work-space as default one to reset all the settings.