# eclipse doesn't work with ubuntu 16.04

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I just installed ubuntu 16.04 and downloaded eclipse and extracted. When i start eclipse the welcome page is empty.

When i start the eclipse marketplace nothing happens.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: The same here , just download `Eclipse Luna` not `Eclipse mars` it will work  , hopefully..

Comment: The same happens also for Ubuntu 16.04 and Eclipse Luna with the solutions below not working for JRE 8

Comment: Try with the JDK 8.

Comment: JDK 8 does not help..

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Try to start Eclipse after editing your `eclipse.ini` file and tweaking the `launcher` entry like this:

```
--launcher.GTK_version
2
```

Example file:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.GTK_version
2
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
```

Comment: I added this in the eclipse.ini and it worked. This worked from shell script too.

Comment: Better than "tweak" I would use the term "add". I added the 2 lines to the eclipse.ini file and it worked.

Comment: Thank you! Had this issue today with xubuntu and the Xilinx SDK.

Answer (score 16):

It's probably due to the GTK 3 SWT implementation. Eclipse should work perfectly with GTK 2, but uses GTK 3 on recent ubuntu.

Do a test in the command line to verify it:

1. Disable GTK: `export SWT_GTK3=0`
2. Launch eclipse in the same session: `eclipse`

If it works, make it permanent. Locate eclipse.desktop and add:

```
Exec=env SWT_GTK3=0 eclipse
```

Comment: Sorry it didn't work for you, but this advice worked for me. Before, my Eclipse (running on Ubuntu 16.04, using openjdk-8-jre) wasn't able to open windows like Window->Preferences or Help->Install New Software..., and options like Edit->Find/Replace... were greyed out in the menu, even while I was in an editor. Windows that were meant to popup at startup only appeared when I quit Eclipse. All this was fixed by setting SWT_GTK3=0, as above.

Comment: Fixed it it for me (Kubuntu 14.04). Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Open `eclipse.ini` and add the following

```
--launcher.GTK_version
2
```

before `--launcher.appendVmargs`