# Broken toolbars in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, toolbar

I am experiencing an issue with Eclipse's toolbars (Eclipse Neon) - most of them are not visible and I don't know how to show it. I even tried to reinstall Eclipse, but (I don't exactly remember) either it did not help at all, or it did, but Eclipse had crashed once and toolbars disappeared again.

The perspective bar is missing, so is the Run toolbar and I think a few others as well. This is how it looks:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45hhD.png)

Toolbars broke after the update to Neon, before that no problem existed.

Comment: Same here, on Kubuntu 14.04... the other toolbars you are missing are Search and Navigate.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36822242/eclipse-doesnt-work-with-ubuntu-16-04/36825434#36825434) worked for me (ie, the SWT_GTK3 environment variable).