# How can I start Eclipse Neon/Oxygen under Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, gtk3

I use Ubuntu 17.10 with

```
java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

Since I upgraded from 17.04 to 17.04 I am not able to start eclipse. It always throw the exception:

```
!SESSION 2017-12-10 21:39:32.982
-----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.6.3.M20170301-0400
java.version=1.8.0_151
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=de_DE
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-12-10 21:39:36.095
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [gtk_init_check() failed]
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4559)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.createDisplay(Display.java:958)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Display.java:942)
at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Device.java:174)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:562)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:553)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:795)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:160)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.createDisplay(IDEApplication.java:168)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:111)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1492)
```

I tried it with existing and fresh Eclipse Neon and Eclipse Oxygen. Also I tried the [tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36822242/eclipse-doesnt-work-with-ubuntu-16-04)

```
--launcher.GTK_version
2
```

in eclipse.ini and

```
export SWT_GTK3=0
```

in the console before starting

```
./eclipse
```

I have no clue what I can do to solve this.

On older Ubuntu-Versions the trick with GTK3=0 worked well, but not now. Have you any idea?

Comment: Ubuntu does not make it easy for the Eclipse team. So make sure [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/) is newer than Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you translate your statement to a real hint: (a) Wait, (b) Upgrade Ubuntu, (C) Live with it, (D) Named Technical Solution

Comment: (E) Upgrade your Eclipse IDE from Neon.3 (4.6.3) to Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a). Eclipse adapts to the changes of Ubuntu, but cannot see into the future. Currently, your Ubuntu 17.10 is newer than your Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I correct myself. I tried already with Oxygen.1a under Ubuntu 17.10.

I found a reason, but not not really understood it. The problem "only" occurs when i start eclipse from console as "root". If  i not start eclipse with sudo everything works fine and eclipse not crashes.

Since this combination (Ubuntu 17.10, Eclipse Neon/Oxygen) i did not have this problem. Because i use a complex webapplication with a tomcat-webserver which is deployed and started out of eclipse it was easier to do everything in development as root.

So i need to change my behaviour to get everything running.

So this topic is resolved.